# In R Notebook, how can I set my API key without saving it directly in the Notebook?

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I am writing an R-notebook that uses an API to fetch data, e.g. Quandl.

For my API function calls to work I must first set my API key.  I want to share the notebook code with other developers on my team, but I do not want them to have access to my API key.

For example, my code looks like:

```
Quandl.api_key('MY_SECRET_API_KEY')    # set the API key for Quandl library    
my_data<- Quandl("USTREASURY/YIELD")   # Make some function calls
```

How do I run the first line with my secret value without saving it in the R Notebook?

Comment: Simplest option (still not fully secure), save the key in a text file in your working directory. Then `my_key = readLines("my_api.txt"); Quandl.api_key(my_key)`. Make sure any version control systems ignore the text file.

Comment: For more info and options, see [Managing secrets in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/secrets.html), a `httr` vignette..

Comment: @Gregor thanks for your suggestions.  reading for the local file directory should work.